# Calculating AUC from continuous output

Tags: auc

Calculating AUC for one threshold in the continuous output is simple:

```
AUC = (TPR - FPR + 1) / 2;
```

What if I want to calculate AUC for multiple thresholds in continuous output of the classifier?

Comment: That is not AUROC.  AUROC uses all possible thresholds, or more intuitively, can be defined by a rank correlation between predicted and observed without any notion of thresholds, using a concordance probability ($c$-index).